# Problem detaching entire object graph in GAE-J with JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to load the full object graph for User, which contains a 
collection of decks, which then contains a collection of cards, as 
such: 
User:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true") 
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE) 
@FetchGroup(name = "decks", members = { @Persistent(name = 
"_Decks") }) 
public abstract class User { 
    @PrimaryKey 
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY) 
    protected Key _ID; 
    @Persistent 
    protected String _UniqueIdentifier; 
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "_Owner") 
    @Element(dependent = "true") 
    protected Set<Deck> _Decks; 
        protected User() 
    { 
    } 
}
```

Each Deck has a collection of Cards, as such:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true") 
@FetchGroup(name = "cards", members = { @Persistent(name = 
"_Cards") }) 
public class Deck { 
    @PrimaryKey 
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY) 
    private Key _ID; 
    @Persistent 
    String _Name; 
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "_Parent") 
    @Element(dependent = "true") 
        private Set<Card> _Cards =  new HashSet<Card>(); 
    @Persistent 
        private Set<String> _Tags = new HashSet<String>(); 
    @Persistent 
    private User _Owner; 
}
```

And finally, each card:

```
@PersistenceCapable 
public class Card { 
    @PrimaryKey 
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY) 
    private Key _ID; 
   @Persistent 
    private Text _Question; 
    @Persistent 
    private Text _Answer; 
    @Persistent 
    private Deck _Parent; 
}
```

I am trying to retrieve and then detach the entire object graph.  I 
can see in the debugger that it loads fine, but then when I get to 
detaching, I can't make anything beyond the User object load.  (No 
Decks, no Cards).  At first I tried without a transaction to simply 
"touch" all the fields on the attached object before detaching, but 
that didn't help.  Then I tried adding everything to the default fetch 
group, but that just generated warnings about GAE not supporting 
joins.  I tried setting the fetch plan's max fetch depth to -1, but 
that didn't do it.  Finally, I tried using FetchGroups as you can see 
above, and then retrieving with the following code:

```
    PersistenceManager pm = _pmf.getPersistenceManager(); 
                pm.setDetachAllOnCommit(true); 
                pm.getFetchPlan().setGroup("decks"); 
                pm.getFetchPlan().setGroup("cards"); 
                Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction(); 
                Query query = null; 
            try { 
                tx.begin(); 
                        query = pm.newQuery(GoogleAccountsUser.class); //Subclass of User 
                        query.setFilter("_UniqueIdentifier == TheUser"); 
                        query.declareParameters("String TheUser"); 
                        List<User> results = (List<User>)query.execute(ID); //ID = Supplied 
parameter 
                        //TODO: Test for more than one result and throw 
                        if(results.size() == 0) 
                        { 
                                tx.commit(); 
                                return null; 
                        } 
                        else 
                        { 
                                User usr = (User)results.get(0); 
                                //usr = pm.detachCopy(usr); 
                                tx.commit(); 
                                return usr; 
                        } 
            } finally { 
                query.closeAll(); 
                    if (tx.isActive()) 
                    { 
                        tx.rollback(); 
                    } 
                pm.close(); 
            }
```

This also doesn't work, and I'm running out of ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure reading of the log (Debug level) would tell you way more, since it certainly tells you when it is detaching things. Perhaps GAE/J is not respecting lazy loading at detach ? DataNucleus itself works fine, with all other datastores.

Why call FetchPlan.setGroup() when that overwrites all existing groups ? addGroup() makes more sense to me.

Comment: Changing setGroup() to addGroup() totally fixed it.  Thank you!  Amazing how I can have almost everything right and that one little mistake cost me days... I guess its what happens with being new to a complex framework.